# Use of Delaunay Triangulation and Voronoi Diagram to find alpha shape using Edelsbrunner's algorithm

Tags: problem-solving, computational-geometry, polygons, geometry

I am learning how to find the shape of  a set of points in 2-D. I understand that Alpha Shape method is a good way to find the shape of a set of points.

Alpha Shape was originally introduced by H. Edelsbrunner, D. G. Kirckpatrick and R. Seidel. **On the shape of a set of points in the plane.**

They used **Delaunay Triangulation** and **Voronoi Diagram** to find the boundary points and boundary edges.

I can understand how to do **Delaunay Triangulation** and **Voronoi Diagram**,  but I could not understand how this two idea helps to find the boundary point and boundary edges?

I look at the document "[Introduction to Alpha Shapes](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ddm/texts/Delaunay/alphashapes.pdf)" by Kaspar Fischer which illustrated the above method. But I still have doubts.

Can anyone please help me to understand this ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Broken link....

Comment: Thanks for attention. I edited it...

Comment: If your question is "please explain the whole alpha-shape algorithm to me" then it may be too broad in scope for this site. You will be more likely to get help if you can narrow your question down to a specific part that you do not understand.

Comment: @Janak Please include the the year of  Edelsbrunner's paper. (I think it was 1983) . Then refer to specific  text/section/picture that you don't understand. If there are many, you may start with one of them.